# Как убрать панель навигации Android 5.0+

Tags: java, android, android-studio, процесс, navigationbar

Работаю с приложением-киоском на **Android 5.1.1**. Нужно убрать панель навигации, чтобы пользователь не смог выходить из приложения. Следующий код работал на предыдущих версиях Android:

```
        String ProcID = "79";
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            ProcID = "42";
            Log.i("XXXX Log", "ICS");
        } else {
            Log.i("XXXX Log", "HONEYCOMB");
        }
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "service call activity " + ProcID + " s16 com.android.systemui" });
        proc.waitFor();
```

Полагаю, что нужно изменить ProcID. Только вот какой номер процесса навигационной панели в этой версии Android и где его найти - не знаю.

Comment: господи, какой страшный хак - ужас :)

Comment: В Android 5.0 завезли функцию Activity.startLockTask(). При ее вызове приложение переходит в режим киоска, но есть один минус, пользователь может самостоятельно отключить этот режим при помощи зажатия комбинации клавиш(на каждом устройстве по разному). Если есть возможность физически заблокировать хардварные кнопки, то это лучший вариант

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с API=19 это можно делать без таких страшных хаков.

Вам нужен [Immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку.
Нужно полностью скрывать панель без возможности её вызова свайпом и т.д.
Как я понимаю, Immersive mode не поддерживает это.